# Laravel 5 Unable to access currently logged in user id from custom helper

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In AppServiceProvider, I called a function from a custom helper as follows:

```
public function boot()
    {
        View::share('tree', customhelper::generateSiteTree(0));
    }
```

The custom helper file is calling the database function as below:

```
$children = UserPermission::getLeftNavByUserId($startAt);
```

In the custom helper function, I want to pass the current logged in user ID however, `dd(Auth::user())` is returning `null`.

How can I pass the `Auth::user()->id` with the method

```
getLeftNavByUserId($startAt, Auth::user()->id);
```

Comment: You can try with "\Auth::user()->id" this. 

OR

$currentUser = app('Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard')->user();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable (or Facade) isn't available yet. One way to solve this is by using a view composer.

```
View::composer('my.view.with.children', function(View $view){
    $view->with('children', UserPermission::getLeftNavByUserId($startAt, Auth::id()));
});
```

Ofcourse you need to add a check if the user is logged in or not etc.

Comment: Can you explain it SessionMiddleware?

Comment: It shouldn't really be in any middleware as it has nothing to do with your request. Best to keep it in the view composer as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Custom helper function will be initialized in application instance before the `Auth` middleware therfore it will always be null, if you want to use the auth user bind it from middlware instead.

Comment: Depends on where you want to add it, you need to add it in the middlewar stack after the `SessionMiddleware` else you still have null

Comment: Can you please explain the same with some codes/ example/ reference?